# How to show a text box if value in tablix is empty in RDLC report

Tags: c#, rdlc

How to dispaly a message or show a text box if there are no values in another tablix in RDLC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `TextBox` and setting its `.Hidden` property like this:

```
=IIf(CountRows("YourTablixDataSet") = 0, False, True)
```

[CountRows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255215.aspx) counts all rows in a specified scope, including rows that have null values, so you can use it outside a `Tablix`.

As you explained in your comment your `DataSet` always contains rows and you need to evaluate if a particolar column contains a valid value. From your code seems that you can put this `TextBox` inside your `Tablix` so a better expression could be:

```
=IIf(Sum(IIf(Fields!EnvelopeToBeFollowed.Value <> 0, 1, 0), "FollowUpReportExaminerDataSet") > 0, False, True)
```

This expression counts how many values are different from zero; I don't think your `EnvelopeToBeFollowed` could be less than zero but with a simple `Sum` if you sum +1 and -1 you obtain 0, also if there 2 valid values in your `DataSet`.

Comment: Thank you very much tezzo. But Text box is always invisible. My data set name is "FollowUpReportExaminerDataSet" . I entered expression as follows=IIf(CountRows("FollowUpReportExaminerDataSet") = 0, false, true)

Comment: Try creating another Textbox with this simple expression: =CountRows("FollowUpReportExaminerDataSet")
It returns a number or an error?

Comment: It returns number of rows. no error.it is a problem with data set. actually it is not empty.I need to make it empty based on a particular column.I need to hide the tablix if sum of a particular column is zero.What should I do for that ? thanks in advance tezzo

Comment: I added an expression                      =iif(SUM(Fields!EnvelopeToBeFollowed.Value, "FollowUpReportExaminerDataSet")=0,false,true)                                                           Now it is working fine... Thank you tezzo